# Foreach multiple result set print in HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I am trying to pull two results from 2 sql statements and print into HTML table.
but some how results are not coming correct.please hel me to resolve.

Below is code 2nd result is not printing correct results - duplicated results.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result1=$wpdb->get_results("select post_name,id,cat from wp_posts where post_name like '%java%');
$result2=$wpdb->get_results("select post_name,id,cat from wp_posts where post_name like '%oracle%');
?>
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>JAVA</th>
            <th>ORACLE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($result1 as $rows1) { ?>
<?php foreach($result2 as $rows2) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td> <?php echo $rows1->post_name ; ?> </td> 
              <td> <?php echo $rows2->post_name ; ?> </td>            
</tr>  
  <?php
    }   
?>
<?php
    }   
?>
```

Comment: why you write second foreach inside first one?

Comment: Have you even read your own code before posting this question?

Comment: It seems as bad as possible. Why do you need 2 queries for exactly the same pattern? maybe you'd like to use OR clause. However, you should debug your code for even syntax errors, as ones you have, so do with logic errors with nested foreaches which are unnecessary

Comment: Hi, use single Query instead of two and use single foreach $result1=$wpdb->get_results("select post_name,id,cat from wp_posts where post_name like '%java%' OR ''%oracle%'');

Comment: @jothikannan I think it won't work that way, OR clause expects `col = val`

Comment: try to do some effort before posting a question...
you have not closed the quotes.

Comment: $Royal Bg , it should work...

Comment: Reply to Niels Keurentjes - if you know answer please reply.i am expecting answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      global $wpdb;
      $result1=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_name,id,cat FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name LIKE '%java%'");

      $result2=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_name,id,cat FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name LIKE '%oracle%'");
```

After getting to objects , we put the required values in two arrays so that we can create a multi-dimensional array.

```
      $result_one = array();
      $result_two = array();

    //putting values in array

      foreach ($result1 as $result) {
        $result_one[] = $result->post_name;
      }

      foreach ($result2 as $result) {
        $result_two[] = $result->post_name;
      }

   //Creating a multi-dimensional array so that we can print two columns easily

      $results = array(
        $result_one,
        $result_two,
        );

   //Initialising the variables to be used as counters and array indexes.

   $i = 0;  $j = 0; $k = 0; $p = 1;

    //getting length of array

    $array_length = count($result_one);
```

Now start two loops to fetch data from multi-dimensional array created.
In this case: To create the table properly we need values in this order:

> $results[0][0], $results[1][0], $results[0][1], $results[1][1],
>   $results[0][2], $results[1][2] and so on.

So we have to create loops accordingly.

```
    while ($i < 2) {
      while ($j <  $array_length) {

     if (fmod($p,2)) echo '<tr>'; // So that <tr> will be printed only after two <td>

       echo "<td>". $results[$i][$j]. "</td>";

       if($i == 0) { $i = 1; } else { $i =0; }  // Toggling values of $i from 0 to 1.
        $k++;
       if(fmod($k, 2) == 0){ $j ++; }  // Increasing $j after 2 steps.

       $p++;

       if (fmod($p,2)) echo '</tr>'; 

       }

    $i ++;

  }
```

If you need three columns:

Repeat steps one two and three so that you can create an array like this:

```
$results = array(
            $result_one,
            $result_two,
            $result_three,
            );
```

Change first while loop to

```
 while ($i < 3)
```

And change the following statements as:

```
 if (fmod($p,3)) echo '<tr>'; 
 if($i == 0) { $i = 1; } elseif ($i == 1) {$i=2} else { $i = 0; } 
 if(fmod($k, 3) == 0){ $j ++; }
 if (fmod($p,3)) echo '</tr>';
```

I hope you got better understanding now and can make the required changes yourself.

This seems complicated. But this should work. Please try. 
Anyone please feel free to edit the while loop to make it simpler.

Comment: How to call this in html table becuase i need 2nd result set in table 2nd column.thanks

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Sandesh,i have tested but it is printing in one column,i need 1st like condition in one column and 2nd like in 2nd column.

Comment: Sandesh@ i have tested but it is printing in one column,i need 1st like condition in one column and 2nd like in 2nd column

Comment: Updated again. Please check.

Comment: A good Answer should explain *why* it solves the Question. Simply dumping the correct code is not what this site is for...

Comment: Sandesh good job,working like charm.one small issue both columns printing same rows even though 2nd column has more rows than first column.appreciate your help.

Comment: @brasofilo Yes you are right and thank you for reminding. I didn't have much time then so could not explain. I am updating answer with explanation now.

Comment: @user726387 In that case use the $array_length of the array that is bigger. $array_length = count($result_two); . And also please consider accepting answer if it has helped.:)

Comment: Thanks sandesh,it helped me alot. at last in case if need to add one more sql and one more column how can i modify while loop?.please suggest.thanks again.

Comment: It seems i missed out something please correct me..written below to your code

Comment: Please paste your code in pastebin and share the link. This is not the correct way to do in stackoverflow. Anyway I will try to find the error.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QXzaVLRA Check out this link. Also make sure you have  $result_three array created properly.

Comment: Sandesh- please find my code @ http://pastebin.com/M5wjDkYW  i have created $result_three.i think some where in while loop is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

something i missed out for 3rd result array.please correct me.

```
      $results = array(
        $result_one,
        $result_two,
        $result_three,
        );

   $i = 0;  $j = 0; $m = 0; $k = 0; $p = 1;

    $array_length = count($result_one);
?>
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ORACLE</th>
            <th>JAVA</th>
            <th>SAP</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php    while ($i < 3) {
      while ($j <  $array_length) {
     if (fmod($p,3)) echo '<tr>'; 

       echo "<td>" . $results[$i][$j] . "</td>";

       if($i == 0) { $i = 1; } elseif ($i == 1) {$i=2} else { $i = 0; } 
        $k++;
       if(fmod($k, 3) == 0){ $j ++; }

       $p++;

       if (fmod($p,3)) echo '</tr>'; 

}
    $i ++;

  }
  ?>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QXzaVLRA.  Also make sure you have $result_three array created properly